# Determine App Extensions in iOS Apps

Tags: ios, jailbreak, ios-app-extension

I'm developing a tool for a jailbroken device, to determine an app's included extensions and display related security for each extensions found

[image]

Right now, I'm able to determine if an app has extensions by looking into an app's contents under Plugins folder:

[image]

**the questions is, can we use some kind of a command-line tool to display what app extensions are in an App?**

Since this may not run also correctly because Developers might change the destination of their App Extensions

[image]